# out of bounds exception for java Matcher

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have the string `"id:2 CAT-id:9-101"`.  I want to extract the id values, 2 and 9, from this string.  I have read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

and have tried this code but it throws an exception when trying to extract the 9:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("id:([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("id:2 CAT-id:9-101");

ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int index = 1;
while(m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(index);
int id = Integer.parseInt(match);
ids.add(id);
index++;
}
```

I am also confused when reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html; am I supposed to use backreferences here instead to get the ids?  I tried that later and m.find() always returned false when I changed the regex to `"id:([0-9]+)\\$1"`

Comment: backreferences like that (if they were syntactically correct, which i think that isn't, since you have both a backslash and a dollar sign; i think you just want the (escaped) backslash) would make it only match duplicated numbers, like "id:123123", but even that wouldn't work unless you made the first group non-greedy (like "id:([0-9]+?)\\1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want `String match = m.group(1);` (not `index`) every time through the loop because every time `find` is run, the set returned by `group` gets reset (find "returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation", per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29 )

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` throws, if there is no capturing group in the pattern with the given index. In your case there is no group `2`, hence throws exceptions. You should use `group(1)` to get `2` and `9`. Run below code,

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("id:([0-9]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("id:2 CAT-id:9-101");

    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (m.find()) {
        String match = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(match);
        ids.add(Integer.valueOf(match));
    }
```